# pyodbc connection to MS SQL Server running on a docker container

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc, freetds

pyodbc doesn't seem to be able to connect when trying to connect through specifying Driver. I am able to connect to setting up a DSN but I also want to make connection when user has got the Driver, Server, UID, PWD and Database details.

I am on Mac and and using FreeTDS driver.

freetds.conf

```
[MYMSSQL]
host = 0.0.0.0
port = 1433
tds version = 7.3
```

odbcinst.ini

```
[FreeTDS]
Description=FreeTDS Driver for Linux & MSSQL
Driver=/usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so
Setup=/usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so
UsageCount=10
```

Here is how I am trying to connect:

```
conn_str = "DRIVER=FreeTDS;SERVER={0};UID={1};PWD={2};DATABASE={3}".format('MYMSSQL', 'sa', 'password','tempdb')
conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
```

The error I get is this:

```
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Exact same database details work when I try to connect through DSN.

Comment: Are you choosing the `FreeTDS` driver while creating the DSN or any other driver.

Comment: There is 'Driver' entry in the DSN configuration so I have [MS_SQL_SERVER_DSN]
Description         = Test to SQLServer
Driver              = FreeTDS
Servername          = MYMSSQL
Database            = tempdb

Comment: Could you try giving driver like `DRIVER={FreeTDS}` and see what happens

Comment: just tried it but no luck

Comment: If you want to pull the server name from freetds.conf I think you'll need to use `SERVERNAME=` in your connection string (rather than `SERVER=`). Details [here](http://www.freetds.org/userguide/dsnless.htm).

Comment: @GordThompson thanks! that worked! do you know if there is a way for if I want to user the hostname instead of SERVERNAME configured in the freetds?
if you want to put that comment as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a freetds.conf file containing the host name/IP and port, e.g.,

```
gord@xubuntu64-nbk1:~$ cat /etc/freetds/freetds.conf 
[myFreeTdsHost]
    host = 192.168.0.179
    port = 49242
```

then you can use both of those values in your DSN-less connection string by simply specifying the `SERVERNAME=`

```python
# get host name/IP and port from freetds.conf
cnxn_str = (
    'DRIVER=FreeTDS_ODBC;'
    'SERVERNAME=myFreeTdsHost;'
    'DATABASE=myDb;'
    'UID=sa;PWD=_whatever_;'
)
```

You can also supply the host name/IP and port directly via `SERVER=` and `PORT=` like so

```python
# supply host name/IP and port directly (bypassing freetds.conf)
cnxn_str = (
    'DRIVER=FreeTDS_ODBC;'
    'SERVER=192.168.0.179;'
    'PORT=49242;'
    'DATABASE=myDb;'
    'UID=sa;PWD=_whatever_;'
)
```

For details, see the FreeTDS documentation [here](http://www.freetds.org/userguide/dsnless.htm).